# Custom Directive using ngMessage not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, directive, ng-messages

** Update : **
Here is a plnkr to show my issue.
https://plnkr.co/edit/3U7MHlJw0gcEdwT4e64r?p=preview
I am sure I am doing something wrong.

---

I am building a reusable element directive that contains a label, an input and the ng-messages.
The data for the attributes is all stored in Json object that I get using $http service.

I have got the dynamic data working for the label, for the input attributes and the ng-model, finally.
ng-messages, ng-messages-include are working but...

I cannot get it to work with the ng-messages-exp.

Here is some code to hopefully help explain this:

---

The JSON:

```
[
    {
        "inputsContact" : [
            { 
                "labelText" : "test Name",
                "labelId" : "testname",
                "labelName" : "testname",
                "inputId" : "testname",
                "inputName" : "testname",
                "placeholder" : "Enter your name",
                "model" : "testname",
                "type" : "text",
                "required" : "true",
                "messageDirty" : "jiraForm.testname.$dirty",
                "messageError" : "jiraForm.testname.$error",
                "messageInclude" : "app/views/partials/messages/messages-error-text.html"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

---

The Service:

```
.factory('BuildInputService', ['$http',  function($http) {
    return {
        getInputs: function( callback ) {
            $http.get('app/data/input-creation-data.json')
            .then(function(response) {
                callback( response );
            });
        }
    };
}])
```

---

The Html directive element:

```
<text-input-comp input-data="testName" model-data="ticketData[testName.model]" message-data="errorMessages" message-dirty="jiraForm[testname].$dirty" message-error="jiraForm[testname].$error" message-include-url="testName[messageInclude]" class="input-group form-group"></text-input-comp>
```

--- ticketData is the created form data

---

The Directive code:

```
.directive('textInputComp', [ '$compile', function($compile){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: 'territoryController',
    scope: {
      inputData: '=',
      modelData: '=',
      messageData: '=messageData',
      messageDirty: '=messageDirty',
      messageError: '=messageError',
      messageIncludeUrl: '=messageIncludeUrl'
    },
    templateUrl: '/app/views/partials/components/textInputComp.html'
  }
}]);
```

---

The Template used in the Directive:
(I am using Laravel as a backend and so I have swapped the {{ }} for <% %> )

```
<label name="<% inputData.labelName %>" id="<% inputData.labelId %>" for="" class="control-label label-top" > <% inputData.labelText %> </label> 
<input name="<% inputData.inputName %>" id="<% inputData.inputId %>" class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="modelData" placeholder="<% inputData.placeholder %>" asteriskcheck ng-required="<% inputData.required %>"/> 
<div ng-messages="messageDirty" class="error-list" role="alert">
    <div ng-messages-include src="<% inputData.messageInclude %>"></div>
</div>
```

---

This is the template used by ng-messages-include

```
<div ng-repeat="errorMessage in messageData[0].text">
    <p ng-message-exp="errorMessage.type">
         <% errorMessage.text %>
    </p>
</div>
```

This is where it stops working, the ng-repeat is generating the elements, but the ng-message-exp is not working with anything I have tried.

Does anyone have any solution for this??
What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks

Comment: This still is not working, I have also tried using an inline template function and that is failing to create the content in ng-message-exp divs.  

I can create the content using the ng-repeat, the problem seems to be with ng-message-exp.

Is there any other way to do this?